# Allowed memory size exhausted when parsing a PDF with TCPDF

Tags: php, pdf, memory-leaks, tcpdf

I'm using **[TCPDF](https://tcpdf.org/)** to generate PDFs, as well as parsing PDF in order to count their pages. For one specific file, the TCPDF parser throws an error:

> FatalErrorException in tcpdf_filters.php line 357: Allowed memory size
>   of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 22416744 bytes)

The line mentioned in the error:

```
public static function decodeFilterFlateDecode($data) {
    $decoded = @gzuncompress($data); // <== Breaks here
    if ($decoded === false) {
        self::Error('decodeFilterFlateDecode: invalid code');
    }
    return $decoded;
}
```

The file I'm trying to parse is a normal PDF, 4.55MB, non-password protected. What *might* be off with it, is that it has internal and external hyperlinks in it.

I've been looking for an answer for some time, and most of the suggestions focus on the `memory_limit` setting in **php.ini**. In my case it is set to `512M`, so it definitely should be fine with the ~22MB shown in the error message.

Not sure how to debug this further. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

After increasing the `memory_limit` to `1024M`, the same memory error is thrown, but in a new place this time (so I guess we're moving forward):

```
    if (preg_match('/^([\r]?[\n])/isU', substr($this->pdfdata, $offset), $matches) == 1) {
        $offset += strlen($matches[0]);
        if (preg_match('/(endstream)[\x09\x0a\x0c\x0d\x20]/isU', substr($this->pdfdata, $offset), $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE) == 1) {
            $objval = substr($this->pdfdata, $offset, $matches[0][1]);
            $offset += $matches[1][1];
        }
}
```

Breaks at the first `if`.

I think this is TCPDF being unable to parse this specific file correctly. I will try to locate what is exactly causing this.

**The PDF:** https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzFpQ1iB9xTnbllGTE16azR0R0U/view?usp=sharing

Comment: That message says it allocates ~22 MB, but the ~530 MB are already allocated. Try to increase this size in the configuration.

Comment: @Jakuje Updated the post.

Comment: Can you share the PDF in question?

Comment: @mkl I linked the file in the post.

Comment: A quick analysis of the PDF did not turn up anything special. Maybe someone knowing the internals of tcpdf can reproduce the issue and find something...

Comment: I think you should enable gd extension.